# Word order after "not always"

Tags: grammar

Another inversion that I notice and would ask somebody for help. Is this correct? "Additionally, Mark openly says that not always are his guesses totally accurate". xxx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, in English, to have inversion of subject and verb after a fronting adverb or adjective: e.g. "**Dearly** did he love her"; "**Many** are the ways, but **long** is the road".

In many cases, especially with "-ly" adverbs, this style is now a little old-fashioned or poetic, but it is retained in

"There is *a cat* in the garden" (when **there** is an existential adverb) and, "Here(adv.) is *a cat* in a garden" and most commonly in interrogatives:

Where is *the cat*? When did *it* arrive? How are *we* to feed it?" etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question presupposes that the words in question all come after the "not always". But I find the word order shown in the question to be unidiomatic, and I'd prefer:

Additionally, Mark openly says that his guesses are not always totally accurate

It is true that a negative adverb, or an adverb which is a negative polarity item (e.g. hardly, scarcely), may be placed first in the sentence, with the verb second and the subject third. However, this is not so idiomatic in a subordinate clause.

Not always are his guesses totally accurate. [OK]

? Mark says that not always are his guesses totally accurate.